High CPU usage during screen sharing or video call
While doing screen sharing or video calls over Skype, Zoom, Teams, FB Messenger, or Google Meet, the CPU consumption goes above 100 percent and the system becomes unresponsive or there is extreme lagging. The same happens while watching live sessions on YouTube.
Any idea why this could be happening?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on laptop ThinkPad P52. The configuration of the laptop -

Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12
RAM - 64GB
Nvidia Quadro P-1000
Nvidia Driver Version - 535
uname -a = Linux THNKPD-P52 5.15.0-106-lowlatency #116~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 17 16:30:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
In BIOS, Hybrid mode is set for graphics
In Nvidia Setting, performance mode is selected -



I had the same issue on my Linux Mint installation, it took me several months to find the cause. My CPU was getting too hot and throttled down to 400 MHz. I cleaned up the mesh in front of my cooler and that solved the problem.
You can see the throttling with htop if you enable the options "Also show CPU frequency" and "Also show CPU temperature" in the setup menu (F2).
